# Mac Developer Library Download

Tags: mac, pdf

I'm not sure which SE site this belonged on, so I figured I'd try this one.

Whenever I browser the Mac Developer Library at developer.apple.com, on the top right of the window, there's a link for a PDF version.

Has anyone ever downloaded them all and combined them into one file? I want to download the Mac Developer Library for my Kindle, and  I figure there's no .mobi versions, so I'm trying to look for a PDF version.

Thanks in advance and sorry if its not the correct site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to look at the documentation on an iPhone/iPad I recommend the docset app (on the app store or github).

For the Kindle, there's a [python script](https://github.com/omz/docset2kindle) to parse the documentation (downloaded by Xcode) into .mobi file.
However as it isn't really updated, it may not work for docsets for Lion or iOS >=5.0

The docset from Xcode (4) are located here:

> ~/Library/Developer/Shared/Documentation/DocSets/*.docset

Comment: It worked for my Lion docs....